# openxlsx writeData() and saveWorkbook() create corrupted Excel file

Tags: excel, corruption, openxlsx

When I'm using `openxlsx` to save a dataframe, the resultant file ends up being damaged.

```r
library(openxlsx)

# Making dummy dataframe
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)

df <- data.frame(Name, Age)

# Creating output file 
output_path <- "check_corruption.xlsx"
wb <- createWorkbook(output_path) 
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")

# Write unformatted data
writeData(wb, sheet=1, df)

# Save fully formatted output
saveWorkbook(wb, output_path, overwrite=TRUE)
```

When I try to open check_corruption.xlsx I get the error

> "We found a problem with some content in 'check_corruption.xlsx'. Do
> you want us to try to recover as much as we can?".

If I repair the file then the output seems fine but I don't understand what's causing the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was due to an "&" symbol in the output path of the file, which was not supported by openxlsx. I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/277) which has been addressed, so if you are having this problem update your installation of openxlsx to the main branch of github.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error when opening a workbook created in `openxlsx`, but the cause was different and - after repairing - some data was actually missing in the first column.

After a good deal of troubleshooting it turned out that I applied a style to column "0":

```
openxlsx::addStyle(wb, sheet=1, style=sty3, rows=1, cols=c(0:34), gridExpand = TRUE, stack = FALSE)
```

That's a big no-no. Columns should always start above 0: `cols=c(1:34)`.